# Compress DB by removing unused PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENTAL INTEGER

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using SQLite3 I got following table:

```
| Idx |  Foo  |   Bar   |
|-----|-------|---------|
|  1  |  It's |something|
|  2  |  and  |  even   |
|  5  |  more |wildcard |
```

Idx is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT.

As you see Idx 3 and 4 are unused due they got deleted. Can I make these Idx usable again?

I'm not very firm with SQL but afaik, I need autoincremental to identify the row without a doubt, every other column could have doublets.

Comment: What is the problem with the gapes? And no, don't mess with the auto-increment column.

Comment: I'm programming an MCU-Device which is meant to run 15years and more, so I must prevent everything that raises calculation affort over time.

Comment: What is there to calculate? It is an integer value. The machine does not care which value it has.

Comment: I'm coding lua on a 200mhz device, the SQLite interface is an inhouse SDK wich is not really good. For some selective look-ups I've got iterate from 1 to max, so keeping max as low as possible is essential for me. I'm not able to alter the SDK. I don't want to be harsh and I know that for SQL it doesn't matter, but for my software it does and I can't change that.

Comment: Fair enough. But you can't just fill the gapes and you should not try to manipulate the auto-increment mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) :

> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that
>   column becomes an alias for the ROWID. [...] With AUTOINCREMENT, rows
>   with automatically selected ROWIDs are guaranteed to have ROWIDs that
>   have **never been used before by the same table in the same database**.
>   And the automatically generated ROWIDs are guaranteed to be
>   **monotonically increasing**.

So your question is "Can I make these Idx usable again?"
The answer is : YES but only explicitly, see:

```
sqlite> create table testtable(idx INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, foo varchar(100), bar varchar(100));
sqlite> insert into testtable (foo, bar) values ('a', 'b');
sqlite> insert into testtable (foo, bar) values ('c', 'd');
sqlite> insert into testtable (foo, bar) values ('e', 'd');
sqlite> insert into testtable (foo, bar) values ('g', 'g');
sqlite> select * from testtable;
1|a|b
2|c|d
3|e|d
4|g|g
sqlite> delete from testtable where idx = 2;
sqlite> select * from testtable;
1|a|b
3|e|d
4|g|g
sqlite> insert into testtable (foo, bar) values ('h', 'i');
sqlite> select * from testtable;
1|a|b
3|e|d
4|g|g
5|h|i
sqlite> insert into testtable (idx, foo, bar) values (2, 'j', 'k');
sqlite> select * from testtable;
1|a|b
2|j|k
3|e|d
4|g|g
5|h|i
sqlite>
```